# Initializing Emacs in the top left corner

Tags: emacs, screen, frame, init

How to start emacs in the top left corner filling half the screen?
Altering the frame size works, but what about starting position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about other OSes, but at least in Linux, you can start emacs with the `-g` (geometry) option:

```
emacs -g WIDTHxHEIGHT+XPOS+YPOS
```